# Ruby Cucumber - Page Object: How to verify expected error page when try to visit a non-authorized page?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, pageobjects

In my test, I want to verify that a user who does not have the right access should not be able to access certain page(URL): e.g. The following URL should only be accessed by a user who has a teacher role assigned.

```
   http://learning4fun-xx.com/forteacher/
```

When a user who does not have a teacher role assigned e.g. a student, but tries to visit this URL above, this user will be directed to the URL/page below with a not-authorized message on the page.

```
   http://learning4fun-xx.com/notauthorized/
```

How do I achieve that by using page-object?

My feature file:

```
Scenario: User Role test.
   Given I am logged in as a student.
   When I am trying to visit teacher page.
   Then I am not authorized.
```

Should I do this way? What to verify is a correct testing? (step_definitions)

```
  Given(/^I am logged in as a student\.$/) do
    visit(LoginPage).login
  end

  When(/^I am trying to visit teacher page\.$/) do
    visit(TeacherPage)
  end

  Then(/^I am not authorized\.$/) do
    visit(NotAuthorizedPage).should_contain_warning_message 'Not Authorized'
  end
```

The steps above passed, even visit(TeacherPage), which is confusing to me. That page does not display at all, it actually directs the user/student access to the second URL:

```
  http://learning4fun-xx.com/notauthorized/
```

How do I test this scenario? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: `visit(TeacherPage)` does not contain an expectation, only an action. Redirecting to another page isn't necessarily an error either, so it seems your test is not catching the failure. Not sure exactly what you should write but see rspec's `redirect_to` matcher - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/redirect-to-matcher

Comment: not related to your question, but absent a good reason it is security best practices to return a 404 - page not found instead of a not authorized when a user should not be able to access content. A "not authorized" just tells an attacker this is something juicy at this location worth trying to grab.

Answer (score 0):

You should [take a look](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/lib/page-object/page_factory.rb) at the `visit_page` and `on_page` code for PageFactory . Calling `visit(SomePage)` doesn't perform any sort of verification of what's on the page; the only time any sort of inspection of page elements happens is when you invoke one of the methods PageObject generates (e.g. a click, check for presence, etc.).

If you want a step to potentially fail, it has to potentially issue some sort of runtime error. You can use RSpec expectations or PageObject's wait methods or something.

If you want `visit_page` to throw an error, you have to provide your own custom verification code within a method named `initialize_page` that verifies (using, most likely, a `wait_until` or `when_present` method) that some element unique to the page in question has rendered.

By the way, `visit(NotAuthorizedPage)` will direct the browser to that page no matter what, resulting in a passing step. You'll want `on(NotAuthorizedPage)`, although since you're just checking for the presence of text and not whether the right page has loaded, you can technically do `on(AnyPageAtAll)`.

Hope that helps.